# how creat Next And Back Buttons To Split Post In Blogger

Tags: button, pagination, blogger

For starters I want you to read Next and Prev Buttons for Blogger Themes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFoEn.png)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The code about blog-pager in every blogger template is the following if you want this...

```
<div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
        <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
          <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
          <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><data:newerPageTitle/></a>
          </span>
        </b:if>

        <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
          <span id='blog-pager-older-link'>
          <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><data:olderPageTitle/></a>
          </span>
        </b:if>


        <b:if cond='data:mobileLinkUrl'>
          <div class='blog-mobile-link'>
            <a expr:href='data:mobileLinkUrl'><data:mobileLinkMsg/></a>
          </div>
        </b:if>

      </div>
```